# Identify this tree

Tags: identification

Can someone please help in identifying this tree? I am interested in planting one in my backyard. I am based near Folsom, CA. This picture was taken around Feb 2018.

[image]

Comment: Need more info please, like where are you in the world and is this tree in flower right now, and preferably some close up pics of the blossom and of the trunk of the tree

Comment: OK I will try to see if I can go retake some more pictures. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like cherry blossom, or other species of *Prunus*. Close up of the fruit will also help to identify it.

Comment: Could be flowering crab apple. As well as I can see, bark does not look smooth and cherryish, but is rather rough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99.9% sure this is a crabapple. It's super difficult to know exactly what kind because they are grafted and have a huge amount of variance between nurseries.
If you ask the person who owns the property, they may know the cultivar.
Also, a picture of flower, bark, and leaves, if possible are helpful for identification. The bark, from what I can tell, makes me think it's a crabapple, rather than a cherry.